# Using 5V, 2 A charger to charge a 7.4 V, 5000 mAh Battery

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, dc-dc-converter, lithium-ion, protection

I am designing a product that has a 7.4 V, 5000 mAh battery (Two li-ion cells connected in series). Is it advisable to charge it with a 5V, 2 A charger?

If no then what are the issues which we may face?

Comment: No, it is not advisable. The 5V 2A device does not sound like a charger, it sounds like a power supply, so it should not be connected to batteries anyway to prevent damage and fire.

Comment: The 5V, 2A is a standard Nokia charger. Then too its not advisable?

Comment: 7.4 V can't be charged using 5.0V.

Comment: It is "impossible" to directly use a 5v power supply to charge a 7.4V LiIon battery. An easy solution is to acquire a USB to 2 cell LiIon charger. These are available. ||

Comment: EXAMPLE ONLY (here)[https://www.ebay.com/itm/5V-USB-Charger-Module-for-2S-7-4V-Lithium-Li-ion-Li-Po-18650-Battery-Packs-8-4V/191962281008?_trkparms=aid%3D555023%26algo%3DHOMESPLICE.SIMRVI%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20191002091506%26meid%3D63da5464d95042e3bdf26edf5c840f04%26pid%3D101096%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D6%26mehot%3Dpf%26sd%3D293727947001%26itm%3D191962281008%26pmt%3D1%26noa%3D0%26pg%3D2332490%26algv%3DSimplAMLv5hPointwiseNativeNoToraCoCoViewsNoHighIdfOrSortByFinalScoreBlenderWithPromotedViewItems&_trksid=p2332490.c101096.m3021]

Comment: Current capabilities need checking.

Comment: If instead of 5V charger, I use 7.4 V charger then this will work?

Comment: You have to charge lithium ion batteries with a charger circuit specifically designed for them.  You have to use discharge protection too which might be included in the charger board or cells.  What you need is a board or set of boards that takes a 5V 2A USB input and regulates voltage, balances the batteries and controls charging.

Answer (score 5):

What you have is not a battery charger but 5V 2A power supply. It is not a battery charger. Phones have the battery charging circuitry in the phone, between the power supply and lithium battery. Do not connect the power supply to battery.

Comment: I have incorporated a battery management system in my PCB.

Comment: A battery management system is not a charger either.